# Is there a minimum range for an Intercontinental Ballistic Missile?

Tags: projectile, rocket-science

To be more concrete: Would it be possible to fire a ICBM Minuteman III from Malmstrom Air Force Base in Montana (USA) to hit Helena (the capital of Montana) about a hundred kilometers away?

If not, what is the minimal distance the missile needs to travel before hitting its target?

Comment: Between continents, no? Else it’s just an intermediate or short range ballistic missile. More a question of international treaty and design capability than physics.

Comment: I'm really just interested in whether or not this is physically possible, maybe with some small adjustments to the missile

Comment: In theory, it's just a matter of changing the trajectory, no?. To decrease the range, make a much steeper parabola (with higher apex). But the missile will have to do a much sharper turn at the apex and it's a question of whether the missile design allows such sharp turns.

Comment: That's what my questions is about! I would like to hear some educated guesses whether that yields a notable minimum range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason why a ballistic missile cannot hit an arbitrarily close point, unless there are such limitations in a specific design (say, software limitations). Moreover, it can hit a close point using a high trajectory or a low trajectory. If one uses a high trajectory, one should take into account the Earth's rotation. For example, if the missile speed is about 8 km/s, the high trajectory flight will take about 1600 s, and Helena, Montana, will move on the order of 400 km in 1600 s due to Earth's rotation, if I am not mistaken. @IamAStudent mentioned "a much sharper turn at the apex", but the missile would have low speed at the apex, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: what I imagined to happen near the apex was that on the rise, the warhead is still pointing up, and on the fall, the warhead will point down. If the turn was so sharp that the missile had to do a near 180-degree turn, how will it achieve this aerodynamic maneuver?

Comment: @IamAStudent : It will not. Not until it returns to the atmosphere. The apex is above the atmosphere for a high trajectory.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that ICBMs spend most of their time outside the atmosphere. According to this Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-V6MZlyCqE) about Minuteman III, it seems the re-entry vehicle comes with radial boosters, so if the boosters are powerful enough, it can turn itself over by 180 degrees at the apex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes..  It would be possible to hit something that close with an ICBM.   The system would have to be reprogrammed.  The warhead would enter into space and would travel around the globe before re-entering and hitting your target.

This is a pretty good video of what happens on an ICBM launch.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOHHtIVP8Pw

A short-range ballistic missile (SRBM) is a ballistic missile with a range of about 1,000 kilometers (620 mi) or less. ... Within the U.S. Department of Defense, a medium-range missile is defined by having a maximum range of between 1,000 and 3,000 km and an ICBM is greater than 3500km.

So - to answer your question - could you launch a missile and have the warhead hit 100 miles away?  Yes, but it is not straight up and straight down.

Comment: OK, this is very informative. The questions remains though, what is the minimum range without going around the globe?

Comment: Present ICBMs cannot travel all the way around the globe. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_ballistic_missile#Specific_ICBMs

Comment: The MIRV stage can be programmed to do this yes. But it is not done as there is no reason to do it.

Comment: A true ICBM has a minimum range of 5500km
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_ballistic_missile

Comment: Isn't that a political restriction? I would like to know the physical constraints.

Comment: The Wikipedia article actually mentions a maximum range of 13000km for the Minuteman III. Doesn't that mean it can *not* go around the globe?

Comment: If you are launching a nuke, political restrictions are out the window.  It is a practical reason... why would you need to go beyond the range of where your target is?  From the Titan III launch facility to Moscow is only 8840 km

https://nuclearsecrecy.com/missilemap/#